# Accessing Office.context.document.settings from Ribbon Functionfile and Task-Panes

Tags: office365, office365api, office-js, office365-apps

I want to access my settings stored in `Office.context.document.settings` from a Ribbon Command Function.

They have been stored by a Task-Pane but don't seem to be accessible by the Functionfile. They are accessible by other Task-Panes.

On the other hand, I can store settings in the Functionfile but then also not access them from the Task-Panes.

This is not documented. How can I transfer settings in between FunctionFile and Task-Panes?

In my task pane, I store my setting like this:

```
            Office.context.document.settings.set('sheet_backup', "foo");

            Office.context.document.settings.saveAsync(function (asyncResult) {
                if (asyncResult.status == Office.AsyncResultStatus.Failed) {
                    console.log('Settings save failed. Error: ' + asyncResult.error.message);
                } else {
                    console.log('Settings saved.');
                    console.log(Office.context.document.settings.get('sheet_backup'));
                }
            });
```

I can access this perfectly fine from another task pane javascript file with the line

```
console.log(Office.context.document.settings.get('sheet_backup'));
```

However, when I use that same line in the file that I have declared as my Function file in the manifest ...

It just returns `null`.

Comment: Updated main post with code snippets and clarification about `FunctionFile`.

Answer (score 2):

The settings may not be available in the function file because they need to be refreshed in the function file's context in order to get the latest values persisted in the document. The refreshAsync API on the settings object allows you do this. It will basically force a refresh of the in-memory settings object available to your function file with their latest values from the document. After doing that you should be able to read them. Try the following code:

```
Office.context.document.settings.refreshAsync(function (asyncResult) {
    var taskpaneVal = asyncResult.value.get("backgroundColor");
});
```